# Copy Data from table of Oracle Database to SQl server Database through Datasets and Datatable

Tags: .net

I have a table hm_item in oracle database which has 10 columns and i have a table of same name in sql server database. Now I have to import data from oracle database when user click button. Which is the best way for doing this??

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `DataSet`; you should just be able to use the ADO.NET command API, i.e. with your two connections:

```
using(var sqlServer = GetOpenSqlServerConnection()) // TODO
using(var oracle = GetOpenOracleConnection()) // TODO
using(var cmd = oracle.CreateCommand())
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlServer))
{
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "TableName";
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from TableName";
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
}
```

Advantages (over `DataSet`):

- no need to hold all the data in memory at once; great for huge tables
- no need to wait to load all the data before you can start writing
- high-performance raw data in both directions (no per-row / per-batch commands - just "here's the data: blah blah blah blah")

Comment: My SQl server database is sqlserver compact edition database and i m using sqlceconnection for the connection to database and bulkcopy class is not part of sqlserverce class.

Comment: @user1578607 then you really should have included that in the question... you could look at http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/ perhaps?

Comment: Can u please give me complete coding for using bulkcopy??

Comment: @user1578607 er, I pretty much have. The API for the CE version is similar, so you should be able to just substitute `SqlCeBulkCopy`

Comment: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' and 'ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer(System.Data.IDataReader)'

Comment: @user1578607 then tell it which to choose: `bcp.WriteToServer((IDataReader)reader)`

Comment: Now i am getting this error. Cannot initialize type 'ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumeraabl

Comment: @user1578607 please check your brackets. It sounds like you missed a `)`, specifically on the `new SqlCeBulkCopy` line`